# How do I let other people use my contract?

Tags: contract-invocation

Using Remix, I created [the Hello contract from the docs](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Remix) and successfully [published it in the Kovan testnet](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xfeec056effb46bb660de11deb66984d7a9f57ceb) (using the MetaMask plugin).

Also, from Remix "Contracts" tab, I successfully sent "setGreeting" and "greet" messages to my contract, by clicking a button.

Now, I want to let a friend use the same contract using the same convenient GUI of Remix. To see how it works, I opened Remix in an incognito window. 
I went to the "Contracts" tab.

EDIT: I clicked the button named "At Address" and entered the address of my contract, but got this error:

[image]

Apparently, Remix opens with the default contract ("ballot") and tries to find the "winningProposal" of my contract. But, my contract does not have this field since it is a different contract ("Hello")!

Does it mean that I have to send my friend the entire source-code of my contract, to put in Remix?

Is there another way to easily let my friend play with my contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the contract address you ve deployed and in remix browser there is a at address button use it to interact with your contract ( the pic bellow )
[image][image]

Comment: This did not work, see my edit...

Comment: Create new contract and past your code in

Comment: But I want to let my friend use the contract that I already created... What should my friend to in order to connect to my contract?

Comment: You could share the code+address if they want to use remix or they use https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts they needs the abi (you find it in remix)+ the address  or you creat a webpage using web3js and share the url with them

Comment: The first solution (sharing the code+address) worked well for me. Thanks!